# InheritedFrom property not appearing in permissions object in OneDrive for Business 2.0 api

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, rest, onedrive-for-business

When retrieving items permission using the OneDrive v2.0 API, the "inheritedFrom" property/object is missing. 
I'm getting the rest of the details: the permissions object, roles, granted to, and even link when relevant, but no inheritedFrom, even though it is clearly specified in the API reference: 
https://dev.onedrive.com/items/permissions.htm

This is my request:

https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/{personal_drive}/_api/v2.0/drive/items/{itemID}/permissions

This is the response I get (shortened for brevity) :

```
    "value": [4]
0:  {
    "@odata.type": "#oneDrive.permission"
    "@odata.id": "https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/{personal_drive}/_api/v2.0/oneDrive.permissionxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx"
    "@odata.editLink": "oneDrive.permissionxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx"
    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    "roles": [1]
0:  "write"
    -
    "link": {
        "scope": "anonymous"
        "type": "edit"
        "webUrl": "https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/{personal_drive}/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=xxxx&docid=xxxxxx"
    }-
}-
1:  {
    "@odata.type": "#oneDrive.permission"
    "@odata.id": "https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/{personal_drive}/_api/v2.0/oneDrive.permission0c69dcd8-97c1-4897-a66b-ff9e206d5224"
    "@odata.editLink": "oneDrive.permission0c69dcd8-97c1-4897-a66b-ff9e206d5224"
    "grantedTo": {
        "user": {
            "id": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx"
            "displayName": "XXX"
        }-
    }-
    "id": "aTowIy5mfG1lbWJlcnNoaXB8cm9tYW5Ad2hpdGVib3hzZWN1cml0eS5vbm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20"
    "roles": [1]
0:  "write"
    -
}
....
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Hanan.